# Load data from Realm Optional into Text Fields/String in Swift

Tags: swift, xcode

Learning to Realm to replace Core Data.  I am having trouble finding the best way to load data from Realm into Xcode text fiends, particularly with Realm Optional INTs. I got this to work, but it feels overly complex with optional chaining and nil coalescing with defaults I would rather not have.  I feel like may be overlooking something as this should be routine use. This is as far as I could get, but I cannot get the Realm Optional Double into a textbox.

I thought I was into something using using .value to convert the Realm Optional to a simple Double to get that into a text field, but then I received errors about converting a Double to a String.  When I tried to use String(Format) Xcode wouldn't accept my Realm Double as the argument, reading it wasn't a CVArg.

**Object Class:**

```
class Device: Object {

    // Properties
    @objc dynamic var deviceID : String? = nil

    var deviceLow = RealmOptional<Double>()
    var deviceHigh = RealmOptional<Double>()

    }
```

**Code:**

```
// Setup Realm
let realm = try! Realm()
var results : Results<Device>?

    // Load Data from Realm with results array
    if let verifiedResults = results {
        deviceIDLabel.text = verifiedResults.first?.deviceID
        deviceLow = verifiedResults.first?.deviceLow.value ?? 999.9
        deviceHigh = verifiedResults.first?.deviceHigh.value ?? 999.9
    }
```